# React-JS dev environment loads but the browser times out and crashes

Tags: reactjs, macos

React 16.8.4; Node v11.8.0; running in an NVM environment on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13 with Xcode 9.4.1 installed

Things were going relatively smoothly with my small, brand new React app that is modeled after CRA+Express (using concurrently).

Then I ran into some nasty issues related to node-sass, and had to constrain my node version to 11.8.0 using the `nvm` tool. I got through several more strange crashes (----------------) and then was able to reboot my app last week once.

Now, when I run `yarn start`, my dev environment loads up ok (slowly):

[image]

Then, my Chrome opens to http://localhost:3000 (automatically) and spins for *several minutes*

Finally, after about 6-7 minutes, Chrome crashes with a memory error:

[image]

I can't think of anything in my (very small, brand new) React app that would cause this, but I am going to try to strategically rebuild it and see if I can re-create this crash outside of this app. I suspect this is a development or environment problem, since I have no problem deploy this same app to Heroku.

has anyone seen anything like this while developing on a Mac?

Answer (score 2):

**THIS WAS ALL ME.** (Satisfying to have it fixed but also a forewarning to others...)

Note: I am 6-months into my journey into React and I made a newbie mistake.

I had added this code with the intention of doing some "webfont loading" (not relevant)

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebfontLoader config={config} onStatus={callback}>
        <App />
      </WebfontLoader>
    );
  }
}
```

Look CLOSELY. You'll notice that I mistakenly put JSX for an `<App />` object inside the `render` call for the App class itself.

I suppose this is where the memory crash was coming from, as it formed some kind of infinite loop.

I identified clearly that the culprit was the `<App />` object inside the `render` call for the App class itself (a complete mistake having no purpose -- just sloppy really).

Nonetheless, I am going to recommend to the React JS core team that this be patch because when it happens to you it's quite nasty to deal with your browser crashing.